# R: Matching by row and column

Tags: r, match, rows

I have two data frames, as below:
EquityData

```
ValuationDate   Currency    Opening Closing
02/01/2003        CHF          0    0
02/01/2003        DKK          0    0
03/01/2003        CHF          0    0
02/01/2003        SEK          0    0
03/01/2003        SEK          0    0
04/01/2003        SEK          0    0
05/01/2003        CHF          0    0
03/01/2003        DKK          0    0
```

which contains information about trades done each day, in different currencies
and HistoricalFX

```
Date        CHF        X      DKK     X.1     SEK    X.2
02/01/2003  0.6885  0.688   0.1347  0.1346  0.1094  0.1096
03/01/2003  0.688   0.6858  0.1346  0.1345  0.1096  0.1099
04/01/2003  0.6858  0.6858  0.1345  0.1345  0.1099  0.1099
05/01/2003  0.6858  0.6858  0.1345  0.1345  0.1099  0.1099
```

which contains the historical FX rates, with the opening price below the currency ticker, and the closing price in the column next to it.

I am trying to get the corresponding FX price in the EquityData data frame.

I have tried the following, which works, but is obviously very inefficient:

```
 openExchangeMatch = match(EquityData$Currency,colnames(HistoricalFX))
  closeExchangeMatch = match(EquityData$Currency,colnames(HistoricalFX))+1
  dateMatch = match(EquityData$ValuationDate,HistoricalFX$Date)
  for (i in 1:nrow(EquityData))
  {
    EquityData$OpenExchange[i] = HistoricalFX[dateMatch[i],openExchangeMatch[i]]
    EquityData$closeExchange[i] = HistoricalFX[dateMatch[i],closeExchangeMatch[i]]
  }
```

Any ideas on how I can solve the above in a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We create a row/column index ('indx1') after subsetting the second dataset ('df2' i.e. 'HistoricalFX'), assign the 'Opening' and 'Closing' columns in the first dataset ('df1' i.e. 'EquityData') with the values that we got from using 'indx1' in 'op1' and 'cl1'

```
op1 <-  df2[-1][c(TRUE, FALSE)]
cl1 <-  df2[-1][c(FALSE, TRUE)]
names(cl1) <- names(op1)
indx1 <- cbind(match(df1$ValuationDate, df2$Date),
              match(df1$Currency, names(op1)))
df1$Opening <- op1[indx1]
df1$Closing <- cl1[indx1]
df1
#  ValuationDate Currency Opening Closing
#1    02/01/2003      CHF  0.6885  0.6880
#2    02/01/2003      DKK  0.1347  0.1346
#3    03/01/2003      CHF  0.6880  0.6858
#4    02/01/2003      SEK  0.1094  0.1096
#5    03/01/2003      SEK  0.1096  0.1099
#6    04/01/2003      SEK  0.1099  0.1099
#7    05/01/2003      CHF  0.6858  0.6858
#8    03/01/2003      DKK  0.1346  0.1345
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ValuationDate = c("02/01/2003", "02/01/2003", 
"03/01/2003", "02/01/2003", "03/01/2003", "04/01/2003", "05/01/2003", 
"03/01/2003"), Currency = c("CHF", "DKK", "CHF", "SEK", "SEK", 
"SEK", "CHF", "DKK"), Opening = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), Closing = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("ValuationDate", 
"Currency", "Opening", "Closing"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))

 df2 <- structure(list(Date = c("02/01/2003", "03/01/2003", "04/01/2003", 
"05/01/2003"), CHF = c(0.6885, 0.688, 0.6858, 0.6858), X = c(0.688, 
0.6858, 0.6858, 0.6858), DKK = c(0.1347, 0.1346, 0.1345, 0.1345
), X.1 = c(0.1346, 0.1345, 0.1345, 0.1345), SEK = c(0.1094, 0.1096, 
0.1099, 0.1099), X.2 = c(0.1096, 0.1099, 0.1099, 0.1099)), .Names = c("Date", 
"CHF", "X", "DKK", "X.1", "SEK", "X.2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```